# Bug: API GMAP : TilesLoaded event is never fired in some particulars conditions

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I want to display a google map with some specific coordinates, and for mapTypeId.ROADMAP,  the TilesLoaded event is never fired. 
When i ask for satellite rendered, it works fine, that's really strange.

For illustrate the problem, I have created two jsfiddle :

1. OK [satellite] : `initialize(45.5106, 4.91115, 45.5159, 4.9193, "SATELLITE");` http://jsfiddle.net/gyhzqg2L/3/
2. KO [ roadmap ] : `initialize(45.5106, 4.91115, 45.5159, 4.9193, "ROADMAP");`
   http://jsfiddle.net/hem6wn6o/26/

I precise that this problem appears when my canvas is really large (6000x5000) !

But if i reduce it like 5120x5120 it works !

Additionnal informations :

With the CHROMIUM browser, in the debug section (as Firebug is), in network tab, i can count :

-> illustration #1 : 525 tiles (25 w x 21 h)

-> illustration #2 : only 504 (24 w x 21 h)

I precise that the rendered of the illustration #2 appears ok (for a human viewer, all tiles seems to be really loaded).

Someone, can help me to solve this ? Is-it a bug ?

Comment: I think the tiles are loaded on  only with satellite. the roadmap is not based on tile  but on shape

Comment: My response is below. What do you mean with shapes ? network section displays tiles (256x256).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same question has been posted on Google issues platform.

They reply me that this problem was real, and they are working on.

For more details :
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9040

I hope it will help you to know.